# How can I unwrap this mesh so the texture pattern lines up evenly?

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv, faces

I am modeling a car seat and I have no idea how to unwrap this mesh to make the stitching look realistic.

Here's the mesh and texture I use:
[image]

Here's what I want to achieve (see sticthing in red):

[image]

As you can see the stitching texture is perfectly even and isn't distorted anywhere.

I know it's possible to simply just unwrap and align the vertices on the same axis  like I did so far or just make the faces even manually in UV editor but that's tedious to do and I haven't even finished a single side  yet.

Thanks in advance for your help!